# Ignore certain unexpected literal in ANTLR

Tags: c++, antlr

I need to parse C++ files (cpp, hpp, h) to extract some comments from it.
I've decided to use [this grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/cpp).

As it done in the repo all block comments are skipped:

`BlockComment: '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip;`

But I want to do something like that:
`functionDefinition : attributeSpecifierSeq? declSpecifierSeq? declarator virtualSpecifierSeq? BlockComment? functionBody ;`

Now, because all block comments are skipped no `BlockComment` appears in the AST obviously.

Ideally, solution must not be tied to any target programming languge, but If it is not possible, my target language is C++.

What I want to achieve: ignore all "unexpected" `BlockComment`s (e.g. in the middle of function body), but parse the ones that follow function definition.

I've tried to achieve that behviour using modes and predicates, but couldn't succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to change `-> skip` to `-> channel(HIDDEN)`:

```
BlockComment: '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

After that, you can create a listener and override the method that gets triggered when a `functionDefinition` is entered. Inside that method, you look back 1 token *before* the `functionBody` in the token-stream and check if it is a block comment.

Here's a quick demo:

```java
public class CPPDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String source = "void somethingWithoutCommentBlock() {\n" +
                "}\n" +
                "\n" +
                "void somethingWithCommentBlock() /* block comment */ {\n" +
                "}";

        CPP14Lexer lexer = new CPP14Lexer(CharStreams.fromString(source));
        CommonTokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        CPP14Parser parser = new CPP14Parser(tokenStream);

        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new CPP14ParserBaseListener() {

            final List<Token> tokens = tokenStream.getTokens();

            // functionDefinition
            //    : attributeSpecifierSeq? declSpecifierSeq? declarator virtualSpecifierSeq? functionBody
            //    ;
            @Override
            public void enterFunctionDefinition(CPP14Parser.FunctionDefinitionContext ctx) {
                int index = tokens.indexOf(ctx.functionBody().start);
                Token beforeFunctionBody = tokens.get(index - 1);

                if (beforeFunctionBody.getType() == CPP14Lexer.BlockComment) {
                    System.out.println(ctx.declarator().getText() + ": " + beforeFunctionBody);
                }
            }
        }, parser.translationUnit());
    }
}
```

Running the class above will print:

```
somethingWithCommentBlock(): [@6,57:75='/* block comment */',<144>,channel=1,5:0]
```